# Generate unique 4(may be greater) digit random code checking existence in database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am creating a pincode for users in laravel while a user register. This pincode will be 4 digits long including characters and numbers. Pincode must be unique and uniqueness will be checked using database Whether this pincode already assigned to other user or not.

I am trying to laravel str_random() function but it will not work for uniqueness.

I am trying this process in laravel. Can package which provide this functionality? if yes then suggest name of package.

Comment: Where is the problem to check if the 4 digit string is already in database after generation with `str_random()`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    ['pin_code' => $random],
    ['pin_code' => 'required|unique:users']
);
while($validator->fails())
{

    // The given data did not pass validation
    // Generate $random again 
    $validator = Validator::make(
       ['pin_code' => $random],
       ['pin_code' => 'required|unique:users']
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

why you don't try [uniqid](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-generate-secret-codes-tokens) native php function based on microtime